# Multiple touches on UIButton with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, touch

I am trying to count the number of fingers someone touches the button with at the same time.

I tap one time: +1, I tap with two fingers: +2, I tap with three fingers: +3 and so on...

What I currently have:

```
var count = 0;
@IBAction func onTap(sender: UIButton) {
    count++;
}
```

The **"onTap"** function however, fires only one time even if I touch the button with multiple fingers.

How would I track the number of fingers the button has been touched with?

Comment: You will need to use tap gesture recognizer

Comment: Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: I think a button it is probably too small for a 3 fingers tap. If you want me to show how to detect a 3 finger tap on a view I can show it to you.

Comment: It's a big button. Basically I want to count the number of fingers you use on a button, if you could show me that, then that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var bigButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let oneFingerTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"oneFingerTapDetected:")
        oneFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        let twoFingerTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"twoFingerTapDetected:")
        twoFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        let threeFingerTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"threeFingerTapDetected:")
        threeFingerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 3
        bigButton.addGestureRecognizer(oneFingerTap)
        bigButton.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerTap)
        bigButton.addGestureRecognizer(threeFingerTap)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func oneFingerTapDetected(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        println("one")
    }
    func twoFingerTapDetected(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        println("two")
    }
    func threeFingerTapDetected(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        println("three")
    }
}
```

Comment: So If I wanted to make a Tap Gesture Recognizer for all 10 fingers, I would have to do a new UITapGestureRecognizer (in a for-loop) for all 10 fingers?
Or is there a more simple method to allow up to 10 fingers?

Comment: @Bob 10 fingers support is not available in iOS maximum is 5.